# How to use select syntax for group by field which is array in Dynamics AX

Tags: select, axapta, x++

I have field Value in table finStatementTrans which is array. 
How should I write select syntax with group by and sum by this field?

```
while select finStatementTable join DataClassParagraph,sum(Value) from finStatementTrans
    group by finStatementTrans.DataClassParagraph
    where finStatementTable.RecId == finStatementTrans.FinStatementTable_FK
           &&  finStatementTable.FinStatementTableParent_FK == 5637569094

{
    info(strFmt(%1,%2",finStatementTrans.DataClassParagraph,finStatementTrans.Value[1]));
}
```

Is this correct?

```
sum(Value[1])
```

with this I can't compile.

Comment: You can't use aggregate function `sum` for array field

Answer (score 6):

As Aliaksandr Maksimau mentioned in his comment, aggregating array fields is not possible. Aggregations are only supported for integer and real data type fields.

See also [X++ data selection and manipulation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/unified-operations/dev-itpro/dev-ref/xpp-data-query), paragraph **select statements**, last sentence.

Comment: Thanks for responses. But I find something https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/querybuilddatasource.addselectionfield.aspx  Maybe I can use syntax `finStatementTrans.addSelectionField(fieldNum(FinStatementTra‌​ns, Value), SelectionField::Sum, i);` ?

Comment: You can use `addSelectionField`, maybe a predefined query with the field without array (summing all array fields) will work also.